# Mocking API responses for Android Test

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-asynctask

I want to mock the API responses for my Android Async Network Tasks for Unit Testing. Anyone can tell me how to do this? I'm beginner to testing in Android.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own class implementing the same API as your 'real' networking class. When one of its methods, say, method requestData() gets called, wait a bit inside the method then return some mock data in the same way as the real class is supposed to do.